# Need table of content on first page in report that has multiple subreport in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have one report in that there are multiple sub report around 20 sub reports now I need table of content with page numbers on the first page that in which page that particular sub report started.

Is this possible? If possible then if any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible in an easy way. **MAYBE** you can calculate subreports size (fixed? variable? If you use Table you have to count DataSet rows...) and build your TOC at runtime but I don't recommend it!

Not personally tested but you can [create a TOC with hyperlink shortcuts](http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2011/03/reporting-services-creating-a-index-table-of-contents-with-hyperlink-shortcuts/).

This is also an interesting (but difficult and maybe slow) approach: [TOC+Local Reports, or The RDLC with the Fringe on Top](http://spacefold.com/lisa/post/2009/09/19/Walkthrough-TOC2bLocal-Reports-or-The-RDLC-with-the-Fringe-on-Top.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your reply but this hyper link will not work in the pdf when I export report in pdf so that won't work. Is there not any other way to achieve this? Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You can try DocumentMap (not personally tested): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156383%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: It will not work with the document map. Can you please suggest some other way to achieve this? We need page number in TOC. If you can suggest some that would be very helpful.

Comment: Can we find on which page subreport is started to load in main report?

Comment: Hi @tezzo I have tried the different solutions but not success.